# Why am I getting LNK2001 unresolved symbol _IID_IPortableDeviceManager

Tags: c

I am attempting to enumerate connected devices using C and writing the code with VS 2015 on Windows 10.

My header file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <PortableDeviceApi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objbase.h>

/*
Asks the user what registry key he would like to get and then output the key to a file.

@param - None
@return - None
*/
void showDevices();
```

My source code looks like this:

```
#include "DeviceHandler.h"

void showDevices()
{

    IPortableDeviceManager *deviceManager;
    HRESULT result;
    IID const *interfaceId =  &IID_IPortableDeviceManager;
    CLSID const *classId = &CLSID_PortableDeviceManager;

    deviceManager = malloc(sizeof(IPortableDeviceManager));

    result = CoCreateInstance(classId, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, interfaceId, &deviceManager);

    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", L"Class failed to be created");
    }

    free(deviceManager);

    return;
}//end showDevices
```

I receive a linking error for both IID_IPortableDeviceManager and CLSID_PortableDeviceManager.

I looked through the PortableDeviceApi.h file that is included, and those two variables are defined as:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_PortableDeviceManager;
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IPortableDeviceManager;
```

What do I need to do to make the linker recognize these external variables?

Comment: `EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_PortableDeviceManager;` is a declaration, not a definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies settings, add PortableDeviceGuids.lib

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant, that allowed the code to compile without the link error.